# Extract daily email data feed

Tags: python-3.x, email-attachments, data-extraction

I receive a daily email that contains a datafeed. The email contains a zip file that contains a txt file which contains xml data. How can I automate extracting this data using python? Currently I have created a custom program that extracts the data from the xml formatting, but I need to manually save the text file as xml file and then run the module. Is there a way to automate this process?

Example of txt file containing xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<title>Recipes</title>
<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="https://www.recipes.com/recipe"/>
<updated>2019-02-05T11:30:51Z</updated>
<author>
<name>Recipes</name>
</author>
<id>https://www.recipes.com/recipe</id>
<entry>
<title>Salt &amp; Vinegar French Fries</title>
<summary>These crispy fries derive their bright, lively flavor from a sprinkling of malt vinegar sea salt, a British-inspired blend of tangy malt vinegar powder and sea salt.</summary>
<id>salt-vinegar-fries</id>
<g:image_link>https://www.recipes.com/wsimgs/ab/images/dp/recipe/201851/0009/img88t.jpg</g:image_link>
<link href="https://www.recipes.com/recipe/salt-vinegar-fries.html"/>
<g:main_ingredient>Vinegar, Potato</g:main_ingredient>
<g:meal_type>Side Dish</g:meal_type>
<g:preparation_time>20</g:preparation_time>
<g:servings>8</g:servings>
<g:cooking_time>10</g:cooking_time>
<g:course>Side Dishes</g:course>
<g:cuisine>American</g:cuisine>
</entry>
<entry>
<title>Spice-Roasted Salmon with Cucumber Salad (Tandoori Spice)</title>
<summary>Combining a dozen seasonings, including chili, paprika, cumin and fragrant menthi leaves, our Indian-inspired tandoori spice lends complex flavor to broiled salmon fillets. A cucumber salad provides a refreshing contrast.</summary>
<id>spice-salmon-cucumber-salad</id>
<g:image_link>https://www.recipes.com/wsimgs/ab/images/dp/recipe/201851/0009/img91t.jpg</g:image_link>
<link href="https://www.recipes.com/recipe/spice-salmon-cucumber-salad.html"/>
<g:main_ingredient>Meal Type, Salmon, Cucumber</g:main_ingredient>
<g:preparation_time>15</g:preparation_time>
<g:servings>4</g:servings>
<g:cooking_time>10</g:cooking_time>
<g:course>Side Dishes</g:course>
<g:cuisine>Indian</g:cuisine>
</entry>
<entry>
<title>Cranberry-Pear Chutney</title>
<summary>Aromatic blue-black juniper berries, which come from a tree in the cypress family, impart a spicy evergreen flavor to this chutney, balanced by floral and woodsy notes. The chutney pairs well with most types of cheese, young or aged. Cow's milk and aged sheep's milk cheeses are good choices, but this tangy chutney is also superb served atop fresh ricotta or soft goat cheese.</summary>
<id>cranberry-pear-chutney</id>
<g:image_link>https://www.recipes.com/wsimgs/ab/images/dp/recipe/201851/0010/img1t.jpg</g:image_link>
<link href="https://www.recipes.com/recipe/cranberry-pear-chutney.html"/>
<g:main_ingredient>Pear, Juniper Berry, Cranberry, Meal Type</g:main_ingredient>
<g:preparation_time>15</g:preparation_time>
<g:servings>9</g:servings>
<g:cooking_time>30</g:cooking_time>
<g:course>Side Dishes</g:course>
<g:cuisine>American-New England</g:cuisine>
</entry>
<entry>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the txt file looks like? Also the name the file comes in?

Comment: I meant in the text file format and not the xml since you want to pull the data directly from that format.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh that's how it spit out from the txt file. I copied directly. Also I had no problem saving as xml, I just changed the extension. The formatting is correct